# Editor Unity3D, passing values from an object instead of the whole object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is more of a thought then a problem but I was wondering something. Consider a map class and a robot class. Now I'd like to take some of the values from the map to use with the robot e.g. tileSize but I don't need the rest of the object. Is it possible to pass values from objects in the editor without having to pass the entire object?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two things that i can think of depending if you are going to have more than one map object or not.

you could keep a static list or static field of the map object and then have a static variable that pulls the info from the object

```
 class Map{
    static Map map;
    public static Map Mapvariable {get{return map.variable;}}

     void Start(){
           map = this;
     }
 }
```

then all you have to do to get it is

```
 Map.Mapvariable
```

and same concept for the list just have a name or id that you can use to identify witch map